# Is there a scholarly consensus that "touching impurities directly is unlawful except for a necessity"?

Tags: najis, ijma

In the context of Muslims touching pork, an [IslamWeb fatwa](http://library.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=88027) writes:

> Scholars of Islam ([Ulamah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulama)) state that touching impurities directly is unlawful except for a necessity.

I was unsuccessful at finding another, more reliable reference for this.

**Question**: Is there a scholarly consensus that "touching impurities directly is unlawful except for a necessity"?

The obvious searches [`site:islamqa.org touching impurities`](http://cn.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aislamqa.org%20touching%20impurities&qs=HS&pq=site%3Aislam&sc=1-10&cvid=879E9FF181604D0298DA28BF813675DA&FORM=QBRE&sp=1); [`site:islamweb.net touching impurities`](http://cn.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aislamweb.net%20touching%20impurities&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=site%3Aislamweb.net%20touching%20impurities&sc=0-35&sk=&cvid=B2D3CDE8CE1048DD86C49042F6969995); [`site:islamqa.info touching impurities`](http://cn.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aislamqa.info%20touching%20impurities&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=site%3Aislamqa.info%20touching%20impurities&sc=0-36&sk=&cvid=3AD62661471543A4B6C363FBEF0B4788) didn't allow me to verify the consensus.  Although the fatawa it comes back with talk about what to do when one touches a wet dog, thereby becoming impure, but without forbidding touching a wet dog, which makes me doubt the IslamWeb claim.

Comment: Honestly i doubt if there's any consensus apart of for rules already mentioned in Quran or sunnah. Also note the meaning of consensus differs between madhabs.

Comment: I think the statement of the fatwa is more than doubtfull as there are enough impurities we may now remove indirectly but in early days people needed to touch them... so the meaning of necessity in that context needs further explanation.